# Trying to use yeoman, gateway, and livereload error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm following the instructions here trying to get yeoman to scaffold an app for me and then use grunt to setup a server with livereload and PHP but it's not working:

https://coderwall.com/p/bal2_a

The main part of the code is adding this to connect.livereload.options:

```
middleware: function (connect) {
  return [
    lrSnippet,
    gateway(__dirname + '/app', {
      '.php': 'php-cgi'
    }),
    mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
    mountFolder(connect, 'app')
  ];
}
```

I get the following error when I run grunt serve:

```
Warning: lrSnippet is not defined Use --force to continue.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I figured it out. grunt-contrib-liverreload is actually deprecated in favor of grunt-contrib-watch.

According to the old docs though I simply needed to define my lrSnippet variable as well as a few others:

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-livereload/blob/a78fcf5ea3426d4af5c33839bddaf3f14f425aab/README.md